# Kafka Connector HDFS Sink 5.3.1 not able to produce all JSON records

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

### USE CASE

I am reading from an already created Kafka topic on which a separate cluster is producing some keys and values. My end goal is to write to the HDFS in the JSON format, for which I have been experimenting with Kafka HDFS Sink 5.3 for sometime now.
The problem I am facing is that I am not able to ingest and write all the records from the topic into the HDFS. As of now if my topic contains hourly data of millions of records I am only able to write in terms of 100K records only.

The following are the configurations I am using for the **kafka-connect-standalone.properties** and my HDFS **quickstart-hdfs.properties**

#### kafka-connect-standalone.properties

```
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
schema.enable=false

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

group.id=x-hdfs-consumer-group
consumer.session.timeout.ms=10000
consumer.heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
consumer.request.timeout.ms=1810000
consumer.max.poll.interval.ms=1800000
```

#### quickstart-hdfs.properties

```
name=hdfs-sink-mapr
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=10
topics=topic_name
hdfs.url=maprfs:///hive/x/poc_kafka_connect/
flush.size=20000
errors.tolerance=all 

format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.json.JsonFormat
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
timestamp.extractor=RecordField
timestamp.field=timestamp
partition.duration.ms=3600000
path.format='year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH
locale=en
timezone=UTC
```

If I don't use the
**errors.tolerance=all** property then I am just producing ~500 of records.

As far as the worker logs are considered I am not getting any errors in it, so I am not sure what I am missing.

Since I am relatively new to the Kafka Connector and have been trying things for sometime, I would really appreciate if someone can provide some insights on what I have been doing wrong.

### FOLLOW UP QUESTION

The kafka connector also died within 2 days. That is it works fine for almost 2 days but after some time it stopped reading the data and does not produce anything. I am running it in the standalone mode, is this could be the reason? I tried describing the consumer group, it seems like all the consumers has died.

```
kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <server>:9092 --describe --group connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr
GROUP                       TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 21         1186755480      1187487551      732071          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 12         957021804       957736810       715006          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 17         957031965       957746941       714976          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 24         957496491       958212413       715922          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 0          956991807       957716202       724395          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 28         956940273       957668689       728416          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 5          957182822       957899308       716486          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 3          956974180       957695189       721009          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 19         956878365       957590196       711831          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 2          956968023       957685835       717812          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 16         957010175       957726139       715964          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 7          956900190       957624746       724556          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 8          957020325       957739604       719279          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 22         957064283       957788487       724204          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 29         957026931       957744496       717565          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 13         957400623       958129555       728932          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 6          956892063       957618485       726422          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 11         957117685       957841645       723960          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 1          957003873       957734649       730776          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 18         957007813       957734011       726198          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 27         957047658       957766131       718473          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 10         956975729       957689182       713453          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 15         957046441       957775251       728810          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 23         957011972       957727996       716024          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 14         957151628       957881644       730016          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 4          957118644       957845399       726755          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 9          957109152       957838497       729345          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 25         956923833       957646070       722237          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 26         957026885       957742112       715227          -               -               -
connect-ajay-hdfs-sink-mapr topic_name 20         957010071       957733605       723534          -               -               -
```

Comment: have you tried setting `consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest`? By default, you are only going to get newly produced records into HDFS. With that error tolerance, you're ignoring bad messages, so maybe you should log them and skip instead? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the earliest config as well as errors.log.enable=true
errors.log.include.messages=true
But still its not injusting all the messages. In the logs as well I couldn't find any erros related to some parsing issue.

Comment: If you added the earliest config after already starting the connector, then it would continue from the last place it consumed from. You would have to change the name of the connector to get a new consumer group

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am able to write everything now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get all existing records in the topic to a sink connector, add this to the worker properties and restart connect

```
consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

If you've already started a connector, you'll need to either reset its consumer group, or change the name in the config to create a new group

Comment: I also have a follow up question, do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: You probably need to look at the /status endpoint of the connector to see if it has failed for some reason. Or it has stopped due to out-of-memory exception. If you have 30 partitions, then you want `task.max=30`, and you should probably use a distributed Connect Cluster rather than standalone mode to spread out the load of millions of messages